# column grouping in jqgrid with struts2?

Tags: jqgrid, struts2

i want to know how to use **group field** in jqgrid with struts2 . 
i want to make **group of column** in jqgrid. please give me any example or suggest me any website which is usefull with struts2

Answer (score 0):

You can find example of Grid (Grouping) here : http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action